Noun(singular or plural) + collective Noun
What is the correct number form for detailing of collective noun?
E.g. for the group of errors:
Error group
Errors group
or
for the group of students:
Student group
Students group?

You really need to provide more context. This can get complicated. That said nouns can be used as adjectives: student group and error group.

There is no much context, it comes from programming, I try to name variables right way :) and stuck as non native speaker by this question.

Does this answer your question? Plural attributive nouns

Here's the thing: error group means group of errors, and student group means group of students.

In "Plural attributive nouns" are some hints, but no direct answer to my question. It's not about singularity of verb for the group.

There is no need for a plural attributive noun at all here in CP. In all the translations I have done of computing terms, I have never seen a plural attributive noun. Only in something like: Error_message: Drugs policy Even though the Brits use it in newspeak, etc.

Use the singular. If you use the plural when speaking, it sounds like you're making a possessive:

Error group (group of errors)
Error's group (group belonging to an error)

In writing, student group isn't always natural. If you see 5 students at a table, you'd say group of students. You'd only say student group if it was an organized group for students, like a club.
In programming, studentGroup or student_group (the singular, not the plural) is generally correct.

"In programming, studentGroup or student_group (the singular) is generally the correct pluralization"?  Pluralization?
